# Remove stagePadding in owlCarousel at certain width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Does someone know could I access the stagePadding property in owlCarousel, so I can set it to 0 if the window width is less than x px..? So, something like this:

```
function() {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        margin: 10,
        loop: true,
        items: 1,
        stagePadding: 200,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        dotsData: true,
        navText : ["<span>←</span>","<span>→</span>"],
        dotsContainer: '.owl-dots-container'
    });

    if ( $(window).width() < 1000 ) {
        $('.owl-carousel').stagePadding = 0;
    } else {
        $('.owl-carousel').stagePadding = 200;
    }
});
```

Comment: if ( $(window).width() < 1000 ) {
            $('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').stagePadding = 0;
            } else {
            $('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').stagePadding = 200;
            }

$('.owl-carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OwlCarousel has a handy option for this already built in. Very simple - just add the "responsive" option and enter the width for the necessary breakpoints(0, 1000 etc...):

```
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        margin: 10,
        loop: true,
        items: 1,
        nav: true,
        dots: true,
        dotsData: true,
        navText : ["<span>←</span>","<span>→</span>"],
        dotsContainer: '.owl-dots-container',
        responsive: {
            0: {
                stagePadding: 0
            },
            1000: {
                stagePadding: 200
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code like this instead:

```
function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      margin: 10,
      loop: true,
      items: 1,
      stagePadding: 0,
      nav: true,
      dots: true,
      dotsData: true,
      navText: ["<span>←</span>", "<span>→</span>"],
      dotsContainer: '.owl-dots-container'
    });
  } else {
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      margin: 10,
      loop: true,
      items: 1,
      stagePadding: 200,
      nav: true,
      dots: true,
      dotsData: true,
      navText: ["<span>←</span>", "<span>→</span>"],
      dotsContainer: '.owl-dots-container'
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

could do something like this too?

```
$(function(){
    let $owlCarouselContainer = $('.owl-carousel');
    let windowWidth = $(window).width();
    let owlCarouselProps = {
      margin: 10,
      loop: true,
      items: 1,
      stagePadding: windowWidth < 1000 ? 0 : 200,
      nav: true,
      dots: true,
      dotsData: true,
      navText: ["<span>←</span>", "<span>→</span>"],
      dotsContainer: '.owl-dots-container'
    };
    $owlCarouselContainer.owlCarousel(owlCarouselProps);
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the right direction, it does work but when I resize the window the refresh is needed for the effect to kick in

Comment: yeah, when you resize the page, the code which sets stagepadding does not gets executed again. You need to add a trigger to refresh the carousel. That goes something like ... $owlCarouselContainer.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

Comment: It seems to trigger only the first time... if ( $(window).width() < 1000 ) {
                $('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').stagePadding = 0;
                console.log("refresh");
            } else {
                $('.owl-carousel').data('owl.carousel').stagePadding = 200;
                console.log("refresh2");
            }

            $('.owl-carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

Comment: maybe this will work $(window).on("resize", $.throttle( 250, function(){
    $owlCarouselContainer.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel'); 
}));

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable and then set its value as per your conditions.

```
var stgPadding;
 if ( $(window).width() < 1000 ) {
                stgPadding = 0;
            } else {
                stgPadding = 200;
            }
function() {
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                margin: 10,
                loop: true,
                items: 1,
                stagePadding: stgPadding,
                nav: true,
                dots: true,
                dotsData: true,
                navText : ["<span>←</span>","<span>→</span>"],
                dotsContainer: '.owl-dots-container'
            });
        });
```